# How do i use .STRACE file to extract the request out of it?

Tags: http, cmd, request, strace

Hi I am Using the HTTPREPLAY v2.1 I have generated the .STRACE file for the Web Action. How do I extract the request xml from this file?

I have tried the below command but it is not working.

C:\Program Files\HTTPREPLAY> SOCKTRC.EXE /s:81 /e:HTTPREPLAY.DLL /LOG:LOGS\STRACE_IEXPLORE_PID_.STRACE/XTRACTALL

how do I get this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer on the [download page for HTTPREPLAY version 2.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=41566), under the *Instructions* header:

> run"HTTPREPLAY trace_filename" from an elevated CMD (by default, HTTPREPLAY is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\HTTPREPLAY).